# How to add custom properties in Apache NiFi and read them on the fly without up down nifi

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

Like I add some properties in custom-properties file. Now I want to read these custom properties without up down Apache NiFi.

content in custom.properties

```
sourcepath=/home/ist/s
destination=/home/ist/d
```

I want to read these properties without up-down NiFi to perform action like get, put.

Answer (score 1):

As of NiFi 1.4.0, you can set a sort of Variable Registry on a process group ([NIFI-4224](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4224)). If you right-click on a process group and choose "Variables", you can set key/value pairs that you can use without having to start and stop NiFi.

Comment: If you use the file you have to restart NiFi, the process groups’ variable setting from my answer is the current alternative for when you don’t want to restart NiFi.

Comment: hi mattyb can we Configure Variable Registry on a process group to read nifi custom properties by use expressionLanguageSupport. I try but it gives me read write permission error.If you know give me suggestion how to do this.